# Select columns by index whose name contain a sub string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns similar to

```
Run  Date1  Date2  Date3  A.0  A.1  A.2  B.0  B.1  B.2....
```

I want to keep the Run and Date columns but only select the columns that contain A, B, etc. So the output should look something like

```
Run  Date1  Date2  Date3  A.0  A.1  A.2
```

Using filter(like=A, axis=1) only gives me columns with A and not the run and date columns

I tried

```
df.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,df.columns.get_loc(df.columns.str.contains("A"))]]
```

but it says a boolean list is not a valid key

Comment: You could set Run Date1 Date2 and Date2 in the index, then use `filter`.

Comment: `df.filter(regex='Run|Date|A\.')`?

Comment: This selects the Run and Date columns but none of the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```py
cols = ["Run", "Date1", "Date2", "Date3"] + [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith["A"] or col.startswith["B"]]

df.loc[:, cols]
```